# Как в pixi js можно изменить цвет спрайта/текстуры?

Tags: javascript, pixijs

Имеется текстура созданная из прозрачного png и спрайт из этой текстуры, сам рисунок однородного цвета. Как можно изменить цвет?

```
// 
var bodyTexture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage('/img/parts/body/body_1.png');
// 
var monster = new PIXI.Sprite(bodyTexture);
```

Answer (score 1):

фильтрами например

```
function CustomFilter(fragmentSource)
{

    PIXI.AbstractFilter.call(this,
        // vertex shader
        null,
        // fragment shader
        fragmentSource,
        // set the uniforms
        {
            customUniform : {type : '1f', value : 0}
        }
    );
}

CustomFilter.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.AbstractFilter.prototype);
CustomFilter.prototype.constructor = CustomFilter;
```

http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=basics&f=custom-filter.js&title=Custom%20Filter

http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=filters&f=filter.js&title=Filter

Comment: Чтобы изменить цвет нужно писать шейдер? А как-то попроще можно?

Comment: заменить текстуру

Comment: И для всех 65 млн. цветов делать текстуры?

Comment: тогда смотри вариант выше

Comment: Да уж, оказывается уже всё встроено, у всех граф. объектов есть свойство tint для смены цвета.